# Outlook Displaying Overnight Events in All Day Section

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

An issue developed recently on outlook running on windows, whereby events that occur over Midnight e.g. `01/01/2016 19:00 - 02/01/2016 02:00` are displayed at the top of the viewer where all day events are usually displayed instead of being displayed across the detailed hour view across those two days.

Has anyone else experienced this?
Does anyone know a resolution to this?

Comment: @TaraFrost The OP tagged the question with Outlook 2010.

Comment: I am unable to find anything to back me up, so this is just an opinion. I believe the reason you are seeing this is due to the fact the dates/times traverses multiple calendar days. In my experience with Outlook, all multi-day events have been displayed this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature, I just ran into a user with this and all of I could think of is how odd it is.

http://www.infoworld.com/article/3026608/microsoft-windows/microsoft-says-odd-behavior-in-outlook-2010-calendar-is-a-feature-not-a-bug.html

Comment: Could you possibly include quotes from the article in case the URL goes down in the future?